# How can i convert a Standard select input into a react select multible

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can convert a standard select into react select multiple like this in the picture, I use map methode in my select

[image]

this is my code

```
 <Input  id="drug.id" name="drug.id" component="select"

           valid={touched.drug && !errors.drug}
             error={touched.drug && errors.drug}
                       >
              <option value="">Choisir un Médicament</option>
                         {drug.map((value) => (
                     <option value={value.id} key={value.id}>
                          {value.nom}
                         </option>
                                  ))}
                        </Input>
```

Comment: Use React Material UI Autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I use npm react-select it helep me

i use this code

```
<Label htmlFor="drug">
             Médicament
              <Select
                 id="drug.id"
                  name="drug.id"
                  closeMenuOnSelect={false}
                                                            options={drug.map(e => ({ label: e.nom , value: e.id }))}
                                                            isMulti
                                                            onChange={console.log}
                                                        />
                                                    </Label>
```